# Active Directory Export/Import - Users, Group, OU's

Tags: active-directory, groups, export, import, organizational-unit

I have a **2012 R2 domain controller** and need to **migrate all users, groups and OU's to a new domain controller**. This new DC is in a **completely different domain**. I've exported the users, groups and OU's to **ldf files using various LDIFDE commands**.

Looking at the ldf files I noticed that ***all AD OU's and Groups*** are exported including ones my team created and default ones, ex: Domain Controllers OU, Users OU, Domain Admins group, Enterprise Admins group, etc.

Here's my question/concern when it comes time to perform the import on the new DC:

1. Since a lot of the these **groups and OU's are default with domain controllers** will the import fail because the OU's/groups **already exist**, will **duplicates be created**, or will the import LDIFDE command **ignore the duplicates** and move onto to the next bit of data in the file?

I understand that before I can perform the import I need to update the dn records to point to the new domain. I'm more concerned with breaking the domain controller where the import will be performed. I was following the instructions laid out here - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b24edf2-9af5-447c-9f15-631e88eefe8c/exporting-users-groups-and-their-members-from-a-currently-installed-and-importing-them-to-a-new?forum=winserverDS.

Answer (score 1):

-k

Ignores errors during an import operation and continues processing. This parameter ignores all of the following errors:

- The object is already a member of the group
- The operation has an object class violation

  This violation means that the specified object class does not exist, if the object being imported has no other attributes.
- The object already exists
- The operation has a constraint violation
- The attribute or value already exists
- The operation found no such object

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731033(v=ws.11)